# Why are my Atlassian Confluence requireResource includes not working?

Tags: velocity, confluence

I am using Atlassian Confluence 5.3.4

I have a Velocity template that has the following line:

```
#requireResource("com.mycompany.confluence.plugins.my-plugin:my-resources")
```

Then, in my atlassian-plugin.xml file I have the following section:

```
<web-resource key="my-resources" name="My Resources">
    <resource type="download" name="stylesheet.css" location="templates/css/stylesheet.css"/>
    <resource type="download" name="JavaScript.js" location="templates/js/JavaScript.js"/>
</web-resource>
```

My project is structured like this:

```
src/main/resources/templates/css/stylesheet.css
src/main/resources/templates/js/JavaScript.js
```

However, when I compile my plug-in, and install it into Confluence, nothing works. My CSS doesn't render and the browser cannot find my JavaScript functions. I cannot even find the JavaScript and CSS declarations in the header of the generated HTML file. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a few months old, but I faced the same problem this week using Confluence 5.7.1.

**My SIMILAR Situation**

I was trying to render a Velocity template from a Confluence servlet plugin module (as declared in my atlassian-plugin.xml). I was creating a context to pass to the template that was simply a new HashMap and adding my custom parameters to it, then rendering the template. Servlet code in doGet below:

```
Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
contextMap.put("key1", "MyValue1");
contextMap.put("key2", "MyValue2");
VelocityUtils.writeRenderedTemplate(resp.getWriter(), /templates/myTemplate.vm", contextMap);
```

However, doing this means there is no WebResourceManager that the requireResource Velocimacro requires to actually get the resource.

**The Fix**

The other answer for this question is using WebResourceManager which from what I can see is deprecated. This fix uses non-deprecated classes bundled in the Confluence JARs already part of your plugin.

Using `MacroUtils.defaultVelocityContext().get("webResourceManager");` you can get an instance of [`com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.webresource.DefaultConfluenceWebResourceManager`](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/plugin/webresource/DefaultConfluenceWebResourceManager.html). This is what rendering a Velocity template in a Confluence Macro plugin uses to allow `#requireResource(...)` to work.

However, a better way to get this is to use dependency injection by creating an instance variable of type [`com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.webresource.ConfluenceWebResourceManager`](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/plugin/webresource/ConfluenceWebResourceManager.html) (which is the interface), and then either setting it in the constructor of the class you're using (preferred for V2 plugins) or by creating a setter method in your class (used for V1 plugins) like:

```
public void setConfluenceWebResourceManager(ConfluenceWebResourceManager confluenceWebResourceManager) {
    this.confluenceWebResourceManager = confluenceWebResourceManager;
}
```

Make sure your `contextMap` is set with a `String` type for the key, and `Object` type for the value, then put the `confluenceWebResourceManager` object into the context map with the key as "webResourceManager".

The final code would look like follows:

```
Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
contextMap.put("key1", "MyValue1");
contextMap.put("key2", "MyValue2");
contextMap.put("webResourceManager", confluenceWebResourceManager);
VelocityUtils.writeRenderedTemplate(resp.getWriter(), /templates/myTemplate.vm", contextMap);
```

This allowed my resources to be used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem, too.
I have 2 solutions:

**First solution**, use direct link: (you have to pass $baseUrl or use existing in webAction, I do not remember exactly)

```
<script src="$baseUrl/download/resources/com.mycompany.confluence.plugins.my-plugin:my-resources/JavaScript.js"></script>
```

**Second solution**, use WebResourceManager

```
$!webResourceManager.requireResource("com.dasannetworks.vn.atlasplugins.ditto-cost-center:my-web-resources")
```

With $webResourceManager is passed from controller like this:

```
WebResourceManager webResourceManager = ComponentAccessor.getWebResourceManager();
```